# How do I insert elements inbetween woocommerce billing fields?

Tags: php, html, wordpress, woocommerce, checkout

I want to insert elements inbetween WooCommerce Checkout fields.

For example, say I wanted to add a closing  tag at this point -> please look at the image below.

[Insert element here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Y4LPG.png)

I know I can use hooks and filters to add elements before or after the billing section, but inserting inbetween the fields themselves eludes me.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [add a custom checkout billing field under the last name in WooCommerce](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61668748/add-a-custom-checkout-billing-field-under-the-last-name-in-woocommerce)

Comment: Related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38261425/reordering-checkout-fields-in-woocommerce-3/38265060#38265060 & https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59452847/change-order-of-billing-fields-on-checkout-page

Comment: Thanks but it's not a billing field I'm trying to insert. I want to be able to add HTML into that space.

Comment: Well then you can edit template files https://github.com/woocommerce/woocommerce/blob/3.8.0/templates/checkout/form-billing.php#L39 or add 
add html via a hook https://stackoverflow.com/a/61319684/11987538

Comment: Ah, ok. Thank you very much. :)